# Can a macro be set up to hide data and images?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I was able to create a macro to hide rows, but the images wont hide.  What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We can't help you unless you share with us what you have already done. Please update your question with details about your macro (post some code) so we can see what is going on.

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its current form.  How can we tell you what your missing if we have no idea what you have?  If you provide us what you have we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to target the images separately as [shape objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841148.aspx). Like this -

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Visible = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1) Set the pictures to move and size with the cells. Changing row heights - including hiding them - will resize the picture along with them. Right-click on the image and click `Format Shape...` down at the bottom. Click on `Properties` on the left and select the option `Move and size with cells`
[image: Screenshot]

Option 2) Hide the images with VBA (already noted by Raystafarian). Here are a few examples.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Visible = False
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Shapes("Oval 1").Visible = False
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Visible = False
```